# Footer not docked to bottom like it should be

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-grid

When adding a footer to my page, styling is not attached to the page, even though the path's are correct. The footer never goes to the bottom, just stays underneath my content.

I've tried moving the block of code inside/outside the main container div, I've even tried downloading the template and adding my code to that, and that doesn't work either. Stock code from the Bootstrap site works. As soon as I paste it into my code it no longer is at the bottom where it should be.

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.container {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 680px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```

No errors besides not docked to the bottom of the page, it's like my CSS file isn't linked, I checked the paths and they are correct.

Comment: body margin bottom set to 60px... change it to: body {margin:0;}

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried everything with that. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Glad i could help. @alfian5229 post it as an answer so you should mark it as accepted. Enjoy code!

Answer (score 1):

`Footer` is inside the `body` tag. The `body` have a `margin-bottom: 60px;`. So `footer` not docked to bottom like it should be.

Change css body `margin-bottom: 60px;` to `margin: 0px;`. Here is the complete code.

```css
    html {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      margin: 0px; 
    }
    .footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 60px; 
      line-height: 60px; 
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    .container {
      width: auto;
      max-width: 680px;
      padding: 0 15px;
    }
```

```html
 <footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
   <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
  </div>
 </footer>
```

Comment: This solution @alfian5229 is wrong because elements with the body will come under the footer.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works fine for me in two different browsers.  I suspect you have other code on the page screwing things up.  Below is a complete example.

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 60px; 
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px; 
  line-height: 60px; 
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.container {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 680px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<p>And the lamb lies down on Broadway.</p>
   <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
      </div>
    </footer>
```